# how can I use the standard Fragment of the android SDK with facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I use facebook library `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'`

And I use method:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
```

The problem is that before I passed `this` - Fragment from `appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` and everything worked But now i pass Fragment from `android.app.Fragment` and method `logInWithReadPermissions` does not accept it.

On the Facebook site i found:
[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/)

but no one says how can I use the standard Fragment of the android SDK with facebook

Comment: try this link, it will resolve your issue,    http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-facebook-login-implementation-with-fragment/

Comment: do facebook login in FragmentActivity with facebook SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the Facebook SDK's `LoginManager` expects a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead.

You can do it by passing the `activity`, like this

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the latest Facebook SDK:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
```

It now supports standard fragment too. LoginManager has 3 functions now:

1. For activity.
2. For support fragment.
3. For standard fragment.